# get iframe content element with class name

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, element

```
<iframe id="quraniframe" width="100%" height="1100px" src="https://quran.com/1?locale=fa" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

so I have this frame on my main page

in the quran.com has a div with footer class so I want to change those style properties
so I found these JavaScript code's but that's no effect

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("quraniframe");
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("footer");
```

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do? As it is, it simply stores the elements in memory, but doesn't modify anything.

Comment: @user1599011 yes i know bot after this code i have error in my explorer conceal

Comment: this error Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: You should show the code that's causing the error. But sounds like it's blocking a cross-site scripting, as it should.

Comment: @user1599011 tnx bro that's second line of JavaScript code. how can i fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can modify it since the domains don't match.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

BTW, not a "bro."

Comment: You can't modify content from a third party site in the browser unless that site specifically permits it.